# Mongo query fields and return no duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do we query in mongo where in we can filter fields so that no field would repeat ? cause as you can see on the result below "Make": "Ford" returned 3 times.

## Query

Vehicle.model.find(query, { 'Year': 1, 'Make': 1, 'Model': 1 }).exec(function (err, vehicle) {
    if (err || !vehicle) {
        return res.json({
            message: err
        })
    }

```
return res.status(200).send({
    message: "success",
    data: vehicle,
    totalVehicle: vehicle.length,
})
```

})

## Sample result

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be68e7",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Fusion",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be68f6",
            "Make": "Chevrolet",
            "Model": "Silverado 1500",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be6901",
            "Make": "Nissan",
            "Model": "Sentra",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be6908",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Fusion",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be690b",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "F-150",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be690c",
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": "Super Duty F-250 SRW",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be690e",
            "Make": "Kia",
            "Model": "Sorento",
            "Year": 2017
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dde068b8911713924be6913",
            "Make": "Dodge",
            "Model": "Grand Caravan",
            "Year": 2017
        }
    ],
    "totalVehicle": 8
}
```

Comment: Can you show your collection in mongo?

Comment: that sample result that is the collection sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the right query for you if you use version `3.4 and >`:

```
YourModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: {
        "Make": "$Make",
        "Model": "$Model",
        "Year": "$Year"
      },
      "doc": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Year": 1,
      "Make": 1,
      "Model": 1
    }
  }
]).exec((err, car) => /* do whatever you need */ )
```

If you need to return only `Ford`:

```
var filterQuery = {Make: "Ford"} // or {Year: {$in: ["2017", "2018"]}} or any other query


 YourModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: filterQuery
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          _id: {
            "Make": "$Make",
            "Model": "$Model",
            "Year": "$Year"
          },
          "doc": {
            "$first": "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$replaceRoot": {
          "newRoot": "$doc"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "Year": 1,
          "Make": 1,
          "Model": 1
        }
      }
    ]).exec((err, car) => /* do whatever you need */ )
```

Comment: but where do i put my query ?  Vehicle.model.find(query, , the "query"

Comment: if you want to match then before `$group` add `{$match: {field: condition}}`

Comment: because i need that query as to filter

Comment: if you add `{$match: {Make: "Ford"}` you will get only Ford vehicles. Makes sense?

Comment: the reason that i put that query is that those params are from the front end where in they send for example param year ({ Year: { '$in': '2005' } }) then it will filter all the list of data which year is in 2005 but no make should return twice

Comment: Why is that {
            $match: {
               Year: 2005
            }
          }, works but  { Year: { '$in': '2005' } } does not ?

Comment: Because for `$in` you should use an `array` of values

Comment: I think you need to learn mongo a little more. Those questions you ask are irrelevant to the topic.

Comment: can we moved to chat Sir  ? I just have very important question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203160/discussion-between-jhon-cull-and-daniyal-lukmanov).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `aggregate` here to get all unique records with `'Make'`

> For example:

```
 Vehicle.model.aggregate([
    { "$match": query }, // your query here
    { "$group": { _id: "$Make", "doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}} }, // grouping with 'Make'
    { "$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$doc"} },
    { '$project': {'Year': 1, 'Make': 1, 'Model': 1} }  // filter fields
 ]).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) // handle error;
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: does not work , this is what i have tried  Vehicle.model.find(query, { 'Year': 1, 'Make': 1, 'Model': 1 }).distinct('Make').exec(function (err, vehicle) {

Comment: Don't use find then. Use distinct only. Vehicle.model.distinct('Make', query, { 'Year': 1, 'Make': 1, 'Model': 1 }).exec(function (err, vehicle) {

Comment: it works but it did only return the Make . what if i want to include the year and model ?

Comment: are you  still there?

Comment: result is undefined Sir

Comment: Undefined @Surjeet Bhaduairya

Comment: Have you changed query with your query? Try it again. Copy the whole code and paste in your editor.

Comment: what do you mean changed query with your query? ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203155/discussion-between-surjeet-bhadauriya-and-jhon-cull).

Comment: Come in chat please.

Comment: here is a sample query ,  query { Year: { '$in': '2005' } } or query { Year: { '$in': '2005' },
  Model: { '$in': 'Corvette' },
  Make: { '$in': 'Chevrolet ' } } depends on what params to send

Comment: Remove you query and check once

Comment: But i need that query as filter Sir

Comment: Just for check I am saying

Comment: i removed the query , still does not work Sir but the answer of Daniyal Lukmanov works but he removed the query

Comment: Are you getting any error. Try printing the err in the console. Also I made one change here     { "$group": { _id: "$Make", "doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}} }, // grouping with 'Make'